# How do I test multi threaded inserts for this struct?

Tags: rust

I have been trying to write a simple storage that uses an atomic counter to increase key count while storing k,v pairs in a mutex locked hashmap.

```rust
struct Node {
    store: Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>,
    key_count: AtomicU32,
}

impl Node {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            store: Mutex::new(Default::default()),
            key_count: AtomicU32::new(0),
        }
    }

    pub fn insert_key(&mut self, key: String, val: String) -> bool {
        let mut stored = false;
        let mut store = self.store.lock().unwrap();
        if !store.contains_key(&key) {
            stored = true;
            self.key_count.fetch_add(1, AcqRel);
            store.insert(key, val);
        }
        stored
    }

    // This doesn't require mutex.
    pub fn total_keys(&self) -> u32 {
        self.key_count.load(Acquire)
    }
}
```

I have been trying to write a test that spawns multiple threads and inserts some values to the same node. But so far, there's no luck :(

Here are a few implementations that I've tried:

#### Moving node in the thread

This failed as immutable borrow occurred in assertions.

```rust
#[test]
    fn test_multi_thread_inserts() {
        let mut node = Node::new();
        let threads = 10;
        let vals = 100;
        let handlers: Vec<_> = (0..threads).map(|thread_idx| {
            spawn(move || {
                for i in 0..vals {
                    &node.insert_key(format!("{thread_idx}-{i}"), format!("val: {thread_idx}-{i}"));
                }
            })
        }).collect();
        for h in handlers {
            h.join().unwrap();
        }
        assert_eq!(node.total_keys(), threads * vals);
    }
```

#### Using unsafe

I tried wrapping the entire block in `unsafe{}` but that threw same error.

#### Using `Arc<Node>`

I tried using `Arc<Node>` and passing the clones to the threads for performing the operation. It failed saying you can't mutate elements when sharing with Arc which is fair enough.

Any other pointers I should explore?

Comment: Your `insert_key` method requires `&mut self` and you cannot share a mutable reference between threads without a `Mutex` or similar (which looks like it would defeat the purpose). Fortunately, you don't need mutable access anyway since your members are already atomics and mutexes. Just make it `&self`.

Comment: After that, you *could* use `Arc`s but you don't need to if you use `std::thread::scope` instead. Demonstration [here on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1131647fa2bcc6b1c40eaa2d4015815d).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering that if the Mutex is encompassing a `HashMap` in which I am adding a value (or mutating it), shouldn't that require `&mut` access?

Comment: You can think of mutable and immutable references by their other names: exclusive and shared. A `Mutex` is designed to enable mutation of the inner value while having multiple *shared* references to it since it provides Rust's referential guarantees itself. This is also called "interior mutability". So no, you do not need `mut` to modify what's in a `Mutex`.

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh For an external example, take a look at the API of the well-known [`dashmap` crate](https://crates.io/crates/dashmap) - all its mutating methods take `&self` precisely for reasons outlined by kmdreko: https://docs.rs/dashmap/latest/dashmap/struct.DashMap.html#method.insert